# Pass bean to servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have the following JSP:

```
<jsp:useBean id="trackingBean" class="tracking.Tracking" scope="session">
    <jsp:setProperty name="trackingBean" property="*" />
</jsp:useBean>

<form action="TrackingController" method="post"> 


    <div id="upper_frequency">
        Upper Freq: <input type="text" name="upperFreq"

        >
    </div>
    <div id="lower_frequency">
        Lower Freq: <input type="text" name="lowerFreq"
        >
    </div>
    <div id="if_frequency">
        IF Freq: <input type="text" name="ifFreq"
        >
    </div>
    <div id="cap_high">
        Tuning Cap highest value: <input type="text" name="capHigh"
        >
    </div>
    <div id="cap_low">
        Tuning Cap lowest value: <input type="text" name="capLow"
        >
    </div>


    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />

</form>
```

This should pass on the trackingBean to the sevlet whose doGet, the same as doPost:

```
doGet..
{
         Tracking trackingBean = (Tracking) request.getSession(),getAttribute("tackingBean");

....

}
```

trackingBrean is not null, but all the values are never set?

The bean is:

```
  package tracking;

public class Tracking {

    public Tracking() {

}

private double upperFreq;
private double lowerFreq;
private double ifFreq;
private double capHigh;
private double capLow;
public double getUpperFreq() {
    return upperFreq;
}
public void setUpperFreq(double upperFreq) {
    this.upperFreq = upperFreq;
}
public double getLowerFreq() {
    return lowerFreq;
}
public void setLowerFreq(double lowerFreq) {
    this.lowerFreq = lowerFreq;
}
public double getIfFreq() {
    return ifFreq;
}
public void setIfFreq(double ifFreq) {
    this.ifFreq = ifFreq;
}
public double getCapHigh() {
    return capHigh;
}
public void setCapHigh(double capHigh) {
    this.capHigh = capHigh;
}
public double getCapLow() {
    return capLow;
}
public void setCapLow(double capLow) {
    this.capLow = capLow;
}
```

}

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: What is the workflow between servlet and controllers ? Any forward or include ? As written it is impossible to understand what you do - and the many typo in code do not help ...

Answer (score 2):

You're requesting "tackingBean" don't you need "trackingBean" ?

Comment: Sorry that's only my typing. In the real world its trackingBean

Comment: `request.getSession(),getAttribute` is also a typing fault ? Why don't you copy/paste your code ?